# How do I make text to speech sound more human and less robotic?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have this app for small kids that says "Good job, clap!" when they pick the right choice, or "Try again", when they push the wrong button. 
The voice is very robotic, how do I make it sound more human and kids friendly?

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(Level_11_Testing.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                    tts.speak("Push on" + rightchoice, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

                }
            }
        });

        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                up.setEnabled(false);//it prevents double clicking
                if (idx == rightchoice) {

                    tts.speak("Good job, clap!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                    mHandler.postDelayed(hMyTimeTask, 1400);


                } else {
                    tts.speak("Try again!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                }
```

Comment: If the app is only in one language (?)... and you really only have these two phrases (?)... then why not just record yourself instead of using TTS?